# Create an addEdge() Gremlin query that won't duplicate for Titan

Tags: ruby, gremlin, titan

Is there a way to create a unique edge between two vertices on a Titan graph and confirm it can't be created again, unless deleted and recreated?

Basically I need to create:

```
vertex1--follows-->vertex2
```

But I keep creating multiple edges for the same relationship:

```
vertex1--follows-->vertex2
vertex1--follows-->vertex2
vertex1--follows-->vertex2
vertex1--follows-->vertex2
```

My basic addEdge query is this:

```
def follow(target)
  grem = "g.addEdge(
    g.V('id', '#{id}').next(),
    g.V('id', '#{target.id}').next(),
    'follows',
    [since:#{Time.now.year}]
  )"

  $graph.execute(grem).results
end
```

What I am trying to find is something like this

```
def follow(target)
  grem = "g.addEdge(
    g.V('id', '#{id}').next(),
    g.V('id', '#{target.id}').next(),
    'follows',
    [since:#{Time.now.year}]
  ).unique(Direction.OUT)"

  $graph.execute(grem).results
end
```

In this document there is a method called unique, but I cannot seem to get this to work on edges, only properties of vertices.

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Type-Definition-Overview

I could run a query before the create addEdge to check for an existing edge, but that seems hacky and could cause issues with a race condition.

Is it possible a method exists which I can append to addEdge which will prevent creating a duplicate edge if an edge already exists?

Or, is there a way to create a unique property label on an edge?

Here is a gremlin session of the issue:

```
gremlin>  g.makeType().name('follows').unique(IN).makeEdgeLabel();
==>v[36028797018964558]
gremlin> u = g.addVertex([name:'brett'])
==>v[120004]
gremlin> u2 = g.addVertex([name:'brettU'])
==>v[120008]
gremlin> e = g.addEdge(u, u2, 'follows')
==>e[2w5N-vdy-2F0LaTPQK2][120004-follows->120008]
gremlin> e = g.addEdge(u, u2, 'follows')
An edge with the given type already exists on the in-vertex
Display stack trace? [yN] 
gremlin> e = g.addEdge(u2, u, 'follows')
==>e[2w5P-vdC-2F0LaTPQK2][120008-follows->120004]
gremlin> u3 = g.addVertex([name:'brett3'])
==>v[120012]
gremlin> e = g.addEdge(u3, u, 'follows')
An edge with the given type already exists on the in-vertex
Display stack trace? [yN] N
gremlin> g.E
==>e[2w5N-vdy-2F0LaTPQK2][120004-follows->120008]
==>e[2w5P-vdC-2F0LaTPQK2][120008-follows->120004]
```

Setting up the unique(IN|BOTH|OUT) creates an issue where we can only have one follower per user. This of course would make it impossible to have a user -> follows -> [users] relationship.

Here is another example of trying to set a unique property on an edge, this fails also:

```
gremlin> g.makeType().name('follows_id').unique(BOTH).makeEdgeLabel();
==>v[36028797018964942]
gremlin>  u = g.addVertex([name:'brett'])
==>v[200004]
gremlin>  u2 = g.addVertex([name:'brett2'])
==>v[200008]
gremlin>  u3 = g.addVertex([name:'brett3'])
==>v[200012]
gremlin> e = g.addEdge(u, u2, 'follows', [follows_id:'200004-20008'])
Value must be a vertex
Display stack trace? [yN] N
gremlin> g.E
==>e[4c9z-Q1S-2F0LaTPQQu][200004-follows->200008]
gremlin> e = g.addEdge(u, u2, 'follows', [follows_id:'200004-20008'])
Value must be a vertex
Display stack trace? [yN] N
gremlin> g.E
==>e[4c9z-Q1S-2F0LaTPQQu][200004-follows->200008]
==>e[4c9B-Q1S-2F0LaTPQQu][200004-follows->200008]
```

Answer (score 7):

To close the loop here, this question was answered in the [Aurelius Graphs Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/03BlqiBWo7E).  Basically:

> we don't really see a use case for a uniqueness constraints to apply
>   to pairs of vertices (a la - only one edge can exist between vertex A
>   and B) for these reasons:
>
> - most times, you can get rid of the duplication quite cheaply on the query side with a dedup(): v.out('follows').dedup().....
> - the likelihood of conflict is much lower (due to the N^2 combinations of vertices) which makes locks just waaaay to expensive
>     compared to the likelihood of conflict.

In short, you should validate edge existence in your application as it cannot be enforced by Titan.

Comment: Idempotent updates are part and parcel of distributed systems.

Dedup works... until you've modified an edge 1000s of times (e.g. changed the weight), and then there starts to become a massive leak of resources.

Answer (score 0):

This prevents duplication in application code versus a DB configuration and solves the issue we were having.

```
   grem = "
      if(g.V('uid', '#{id}').out('follows').has('id', g.V('uid', '#{target.id}').next().id).hasNext() == true){
        println 'already connected'
      } else{
        g.addEdge(
          g.V('uid', '#{id}').next(),
          g.V('uid', '#{target.id}').next(),
          'follows',
          [since:(new java.util.Date()).getTime()]
        )
      }"
    $graph.execute(grem).results
```